# how can reduce video size at time of recording, Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

*ffmpeg*, *mediacodec*, and *mp4parser* codecs are taking time to compress, so is there any other way to reduce size of video at time of recording?

I am using [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) for recording videos but it creates a lot of data, and I want to reduce it as I'm not able to upload it.

Comment: so what did you try with `MediaRecorder`? what does your code look like?

Comment: @pskink two of the same comment there

Comment: bcause OP did non answer my question in any way...

Comment: @pskink my code is very huge and it's not possible to share here.
please let me know if there any way to reduce size of video at time of recording.

Comment: did you read `MediaRecorder` documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate();
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate();    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

i used this lines from media recorder to reduce size of video but didn't wrok for me

Comment: At the time of recording and preview view both looks different, with use of mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer with the use of media Recording Documentation and added this lines in code:

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+mediaFileName+".mp4");
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(18);
mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mOrientation);
```

After this, I get a lower size of video with good quality.

Comment: If it worked for you.. mark your answer as correct answer. It will help others to solve same kind of problem.